# Swagger not working with spring-boot 2.7.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I use Spring Boot 2.7.6 and I tried to configure Swagger but it is not working and I do not know why. I tried to do the same configuration than the answers given for other questions related to Swagger but it does not work. I will try to give all needed information to explain my configuration.

I have this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have these properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/my-api-web
server.port=8081
```

Here is my swagger configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test.api.controller")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Here is my Spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // configure provider and filter
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/enpoint1/**", "/endpoint2/**").and()
                .authenticationProvider(this.preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider())
                .addFilter(this.userContextFilter());

        // configure what is authenticated and what is anonymous
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/endpoint1/**", "/endpoint2/**").authenticated() //
                .antMatchers("/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll() //
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint());
    }

    ...
}
```

When I try to connect to http://localhost:8081/my-api-web/v2/api-docs , I have a JSON but I also see this error in the console on back-end side:

```
 ee4321ce-8c76-4da9-a3da-b8a86da13155 ERROR 2023-02-13 09:51:55.287 springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.ReferenceModelSpecificationToPropertyConverter - Unable to find a model that matches key ModelKey{qualifiedModelName=ModelName{namespace='java.lang', name='Void'}, viewDiscriminator=null, validationGroupDiscriminators=[], isResponse=true}
```

When I try to access to swagger-ui, it does not work. I tried https://localhost:8081/my-api-web/swagger-ui/ and http://localhost:8081/my-api-web/swagger-ui/index.html .

For the second one I have this error on front-end side:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Feb 13 09:55:12 CET 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I also saw this error on back-end side but I do not know if it is linked:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x030xd2f0xbd0x130x07?L0xa99F0x0e0xfbu0xa40xae0xde'0xc370xf70xad0x990xcf0x830xe290xa30xac0x840xd60x0c0x18 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I do not know how to make swagger UI work for my case.

I also saw an answer with springdoc-openapi-ui but I do not know if it is useful for me to use swagger or if it is a replacement?

Comment: Can you please share your swagger?

Comment: My swagger? I do not understand what do you want sorry